# Cause of horizontal scroll

Tags: css

The site is here...

```
http://58b.d52.myftpupload.com/
```

Trying to identify why I have a horizontal scrollbar.

Only on homepage, and I can eliminate with overflow-x:hidden.

But still would like to know the cause and prevent rather than override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#homeflex > ol.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging is the culprit

Comment: That is responsible for some of it. Still some there when I display:none that element.

Comment: I think you have some kind of JS script running that sets the main width, so if you set the CSS after rendering it won't work properly. I just checked the site again the the scrollbar is completely gone, so I guess you found it.

Comment: I never found the entire issue. You ID'd one problem and that cleared some of it. Thanks! But there was still extra space. It's only gone now b/c I hid the x overflow.